# how to create attached signature using openssl

Tags: security, encryption, openssl, cryptography, gnupg

in gpg, with the below command we can simply encrypt and create an attached signature for an input file:

```
gpg --batch --no-tty --default-key SIGNKEY_NAME --cipher-algo AES256 --symmetric --passphrase-file ENCRYPTIONKEY_FILE --sign --force-mdc --output out.bin
```

is there any way in the OpenSSL to encrypt and create an attached signature for a file like gpg?

Comment: OpenSSL does not support PGP formats, but it does have CMS-was-PKCS7 and S/MIME formats (S/MIME is CMS with MIME labels). These support detached (aka clearsigned) and embedded signature (not default, specify `-nodetach`) using keys in X.509 certificates, plus 'enveloped' data encrypted to recipient publickey (like `gpg -r`) _and_ 'encrypted' data using symmetric key (NOT password and derivation like pgp's s2k) but not in same command. See the man page. Note `gpgsm` supports S/MIME signing and enveloping, but not symmetric encryption. This is not about programming or development.